# Is There A WordPress Hook for Accessing Attachments for A Particular Page?

Tags: theme-development, hooks, attachments, child-theme

I'm writing a site with a category that's used for formatting specific types of reports.

The user logs in, and writes the report as a blog entry. When they select the category, the report is formatted in a certain way.

I'm editing the "single.php" file in my child theme (I'm deriving from [WooCommerce mystile](https://woocommerce.com/products/mystile/))

What I want to do is have a runtime (display time) feature that finds attachments that were made JUST TO THIS POST, and create a list of links to those attachments at the bottom of the post.

[The Hooks Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) doesn't seem to have anything, but I'm sure there's something.

Does anyone know the proper "M" for me to RTFM?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like [this plugin](http://plugins.twinpictures.de/plugins/list-related-attachments/) may give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, out of many, where we use the `the_content` filter and loop through the `get_attached_media( $type )` to construct the list of attached media. We can e.g. use `$type = 'image'` for images or `$type = null` for all mime types.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    // Nothing to do - target single posts assigned to the 'report' category 
    if( ! in_the_loop() || ! is_single() || ! has_category( 'report' ) )      
        return $content;

    // Reduce attached media items into a string
    $li = array_reduce(                           
        get_attached_media( $type = null ),       // Fetch the attached media (all == null)
        function( $li, $item )                    // Callback for each media item
        {
            $li .= sprintf(                       // Construct and append each list item
                '<li>%s</li>',
                wp_get_attachment_link( $item->ID, false ) 
            );
            return $li;
        },
        ''                                         // Initial value of $li
    );

    // Append to the content
    if( $li )
        $content .= sprintf( '<ul class="attached-media">%s</ul>', $li);

    return $content;

}, 999 );                                           // Some late priority
```

Here we display the attached media list only for single posts, assigned to the `report` category.